# database login using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

This is the Database entry of my application in server.properties file.

```
umpdb.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
umpdb.url=jdbc:mysql://10.66.11.44:3306/MT_SMS_CHN?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
umpdb.username=stackuser
umpdb.password=stackpass
```

I want to print `mysql -uuser -ppasswrod -hhostname dbname` using linux command.

It means, I need output as below

```
mysql -ustackuser -pstackpass -h10.66.11.44 MT_SMS_CHN
```

Please help me for this.

Comment: Where is your attempt on this?

Comment: To schedule a shell script for release management of applications, DB details of application is mentioned in server.properties file.

Comment: I know what you want to achieve. But what have you done so far.

Comment: I have done like this. But i want this with a single command. user=$"grep 'umpdb.username=' server.properties | cut -d '=' -f 2"
pass=$"grep 'umpdb.password' server.properties | cut -d '=' -f 2"

dbip=$"grep 'umpdb.url=jdbc:mysql' server.properties  | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d ':' -f 1"
db=$"grep 'umpdb.url=jdbc:mysql' server.properties | cut -d '/' -f 4 | cut -d '?' -f 1"

mysql -u$user -p$pass -h$dbip $db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'[:=/?]' '/url/{
                     h=$6" "$8              # get host and database
                }
                /username/{
                     u=$2                   # get username
                }
                /password/{
                     # print username, password, host and database
                     printf("mysql -u%s -p%s -h%s\n",u,$2,h); 

                     # we got what we want, exit
                     # if your file contains more than 1 db config 
                     # just comment below exit keyword

                     exit
                }
                ' server.conf
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat server.conf 
umpdb.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
umpdb.url=jdbc:mysql://10.66.11.44:3306/MT_SMS_CHN?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
umpdb.username=stackuser
umpdb.password=stackpass

$ awk -F'[:=/?]' '/url/{h=$6" "$8}/username/{u=$2}/password/{printf("mysql -u%s -p%s -h%s\n",u,$2,h); exit}' server.conf 
mysql -ustackuser -pstackpass -h10.66.11.44 MT_SMS_CHN
```